# XSLT - multiple input XML, multiple output XML

Tags: xslt

As far as I understand, we can use 1 XSLT to read multiple xml files as inputs. May I know if there's a way to read multiple inputs and produce multiple outputs as well (within 1 XSLT)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a standard feature of XSLT 2.0, with the `xsl:result-document` instruction.

Some XSLT 1.0 processors offer similar capabilities using vendor extensions, but it's not possible within the W3C standard.

Comment: How can we read multiple n number of file at a time in XSLT 2.0

Comment: @AmrendraKumar Reading multiple files has always been possible with the document() function (or by supplying additional files as stylesheet parameters). Writing multiple files needs 2.0 or later.